# Javascript AJAX SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0 in ajax + node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an AJAX POST request with multiple objects to a node.js server. Although my server sends status code `200`, I am still getting the error `Javascript AJAX SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0`. Here is my POST request:

```
     var company_id = "some_generic_id";
     var president  = "obama";

     var postData = {
       company_id   : company_id,
       president    : president
     };


     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/api/test_link',
       data: JSON.stringify(postData),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       data: postData,
       success: function(data, status) {
         console.log('it worked!')
       },
       error: function(request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
       }
     });
```

And here is my server side code:

```
app.post('/api/test_link', function(req, res) {

            console.log('--post data--');
            console.log(req.body);
            /*
                prints out:
                --post data--
                { company_id: 'company_id', president: 'obama' }

            */  
            res.sendStatus(200);

    });
```

Here's an image from my network tab:

[image: Network tab]

Does anyone know what I might be missing or why my `postData` has invalid syntax?

Comment: check your network response see it's result?

Comment: my network response is a status 200.. but since it returned 200, doesn't it mean the AJAX request was successful (instead of error)?

Comment: does it displayed the json object in your network response? check that

Comment: I see it's display but not in Content-Type: application/json format see my answer below

Comment: @user1547174, where do you get the error, on the client or server? when sending or when receiving?

Comment: @Maximus I get the error on the client side. The error happens after the server sends the 'response status 200'.

Comment: @user1547174, but you're not returning any data from the server, right?

Comment: @Maximus correct - I'm only returning status codes - in this case, status code 200

Comment: @user1547174, try removing `dataType: "json"` from the $.ajax call options

Comment: @user1547174, you're welcome, I'll post it as an answer now

Comment: @user1547174 it will work but the data is not returning as parse json object

Comment: @Beginner, but he is not returning any data and so there is nothing to parse. And as I mentioned, with `dataType: "json"` there is no need to specify correct mime type on the server

Comment: @Maximus I see, I didn't realise that I thought he want's to return something/he's returning something on it since in his post he put a json object sample, problem is not enough detail.

Comment: @Beginner, that's fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on ajax call states about `dataType` option:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. "json":
>   Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

Since you're not returning any data from the server, your empty data is parsed as JSON, which produces the error. Simply remove `dataType: "json"` if you're not returning any data.

Answer (score 1):

add `res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});` at the beginning of `app.post('/api/test_link', function(req, res) {` to specify that you wanted response as json format

Remove your

```
res.sendStatus(200);
```

Since `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});` will also set your statusCode

So it would be like this

```
app.post('/api/test_link', function(req, res) {

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            console.log('--post data--');
            console.log(req.body);
            /*
                prints out:
                --post data--
                { company_id: 'company_id', president: 'obama' }

            */  
            res.send();

    });
```

Comment: Hi - I tried `res.send({status: 200})` and this seemed to work... could you please give an example of where I should add `res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});`?

Comment: He specified `dataType: "json"`, so the response will be parsed as JSON regardless of the returned mime type

Answer (score 0):

I face this error if I'm not using `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
$.post(url, body, res => { ... }); 
// Error: {message: "Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0"}
```

```js
$.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), res => { ... });
```